# Android: how to schedule an alarmmanager broadcast event that will be called even if my application is closed?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

My app needs to execute a specific task every hour. It does not matter if app is runing, suspended, or even closed.

When app is running or suspended, I can do it by just scheduling an AlarmManager broadcastreceiver. But when the application is closed, I have to call "unregisterReceiver" to not leak an intent, and app will never be wake up (or something) to process the task.

Then, the question is: **how to schedule an alarmmanager task that I don't need to unregister, so it will be called even if my application is closed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager.setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)` for this. Set the type to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` to make sure that the device is woken up if it is sleeping (if that is your requirement).

Something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.foo.android.MY_TIMER");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 hour
    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now + interval, interval,
        pendingIntent); // Schedule timer for one hour from now and every hour after that
```

You pass a PendingIntent to this method. You don't need to worry about leaking Intents.

Remember to turn the alarm off by calling `AlarmManager.cancel()` when you don't need it anymore.

Don't register a Receiver in code for this. Just add an `<intent-filter>` tag to the manifest entry for your BroadcastReceiver, like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                    android:name="com.foo.android.MY_TIMER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Received doesn't fire if app is "force stopped". Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: You could just use `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR` for the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user an Android Component Called `Service` for this. From the service code you can schedule your Task using the AlarmManager with PendingIntent Class for every hours. As your AlarmManger is declared in the Service Components it doesn't require any GUI and will get execute in background, till you have battery in your device.