# Starting a service on BOOTUP and then scheduling the service to run every 10 minutes?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I would like to have a service run on bootup and then scheduled to run every 10 minutes. How can I go about this?

If on boot-up can I force a schedule for 10 minutes, but I presume I would need to schedule this every time on boot-up because after a reboot all schedules are lost?

Comment: "i presume i would need to schedule this everytime on bootup because after a reboot all schedules are lost?" -- you would need to schedule your `AlarmManager` alarms on first run of your app after install and on reboot. You might also want to have some smarts to reschedule the alarms if you determine, when your app is manually run, that the alarm has not run in too long (e.g., user pressed Force Stop in Settings on your app).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, so hence i still listen fro BOOT_COMPLETED and then schedule the alarm with AlarmManager?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice little tutorial [here](http://www.androidenea.com/2009/09/starting-android-service-after-boot.html) that explains how to start a service at boot time that just keeps running and at some regular interval does something (writes to a log file, in the case of the tutorial).

As @CommonsWare points out, this creates an unnecessary load on the system. A better approach is to schedule a repeating alarm with AlarmManager, as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819196/535871). You can register your app to receive the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast (as described in the above tutorial) and in response schedule the alarm.

Comment: The first tutorial demonstrates the everlasting service anti-pattern. For "have a service run on bootup and then scheduled to run every 10 minutes", an everlasting service is not needed, and users have complained frequently and loudly about services clogging up their devices. Please please please please please use `AlarmManager` for this.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I agree. I edited my answer to emphasize the latter approach.

Comment: @Ted Hopp For my use case, what if there are hundreds of pendingIntents for triggering Alarms, that need to be reset after the BroadcastReceiver receives a BOOT_COMPLETED action?  Since there are many alarms how would I reset these alarms in the background?

Answer (score 0):

in my application I've registered a broadcast receiver on the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) Intent to be notified when the device boot has been completed.
To achieve the result you have to specify in your manifest file the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
...
<receiver
 android:name=".YOUR_BROADCAST_RECEIVER">
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the BroadcastReceiver I started the service with

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 context.startService(new Intent(context, serviceClass));
 ...
}
```

Finally in the onStartCommand of the service

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 ...
 setNextSchedule();
 ...
}

private void setNextSchedule() {
 long time = WHEN_YOU WANT_THE SERVICE TO BE SCHEDULED AGAIN;
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,new Intent(this, this.getClass()), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
 am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
}
```

The [AlarmManger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) will use the pending intent to send to your service the intent you passed. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

bye