# Android : Handling offline Data

Tags: android, httpclient

Hi mine is a small application , user will fill the entries and i will be sending the data to the server(Just data no images). Data will be sent to the server when there is a network connection, now the problem is when the device is offline, what i am doing is after the user enters data i will store it in database and when device goes online it will be pushed to the server (this is General idea).

Is there any better option to save data when offline(faster than database,maybe caching?)if so please suggest some cache libraries also how to invoke the server call when device is online(please suggest some techniques). also this server call should invoke only if the particular data is not sent.

How to check it?

Comment: Hi teekib, did you implement how to send the offline data to server when device is online without opeining the app. If done please share. It will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can program one 'AlarmManager' to activate each x time and check internet connection and if there is data that is not sent to the server to send the data.

- [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- [Example AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818313/android-how-to-schedule-an-alarmmanager-broadcast-event-that-will-be-called-eve)

Comment: Thank you, ok i will implement alaram manager, so if my app is not active how to send data when there is network connection

Comment: Although this application does not enable the "AlarmManager" will activate and execute the "BroadcastReciever or Services" that you implement your. And there is where you will send data.